# Jenkins user has root as home directory

Tags: jenkins

I'm running jenkins in a virtual machine on google cloud platform.  The VM came from bitnami.

My problem is that if I run a job which executes a bash script and from that script I try to access ~ it returns /

The user my jobs are run as is tomcat.  Tomcats home directory is /home/tomcat as you would expect.  If I login as tomcat and cd to ~ it will take me to the correct place /home/tomcat.

Why is the home directory of tomcat different when running a job from jenkins than it is if I just login normally?

Comment: What is the value of the JENKINS_HOME environment variable on your VM (for the tomcat user)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing

```
whoami
```

*in a job*?

Perhaps Jenkins is run by a different functional user than tomcat.
Have you checked the root dir for anything suspicious that would indicate that it is somehow used? Finally, how do you exactly check the home dir in a job?